# Create and insert data into SQLite manually

Tags: android, sqlite

I'm building an Android quiz application which needs to use database locally. SQLite seems to be what I need.

The database will contain questions and answers (which will be inputted by me manually not by using the application), and some tables which store users's score, progress etc.

My question is how do I create tables and import data from other source (or insert with INSERT INTO queries) into Android's embedded SQLite manually? Online tutorials only teach me how to do it from the scratch and via application interface...

Comment: You may execute DML statements (INSERT, UPDATE, etc.) from your Java code just as you would do a SELECT.  Please search for how to use SQLite from Android.

Comment: I would use Room persistence library and import data in JSON format.

Comment: create database on your PC, and then embed into the app as asset, and extract it to the databases directory on first launch of the app

Comment: @VladyslavMatviienko brillant. Please post your comment as answer.

Comment: It is not detailed enough to be an answer. Probably somebody wants to extend it and post as answer. I don't mind somebody to do.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/sqlite but i like @VladyslavMatviienko answer. +1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways you could do this.

- You could create the database populated with the questions and answers as an asset in the assets folder. This pre-existing database is then copied once, perhaps utilising the [SQLiteAssetHelper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) to manage the copy of the database.

  - There are numerous SQLite management type tools available, such as SQlite studio, DB Browser for SQlite, Navicat, that could be used to create the database and load the data. You then just copy the saved file into the assets folder (note for the SQLiteAssethelper the file needs to be in the assets/databases folder).
  - The restriction/complexity/drawback is if the questions and answers changed over time (e.g. more questions and answers were added).
- Another way could be to define the database structure and supply the questions as an external file rather than a pre-existing database (as an asset) which is read and used to insert the questions into the database. With some consideration/planning this could handle on-going questions, relatively simply.
- Yet another way could be have the question on a centralised server (Firebase could be suitable for this) rather than an asset file. The App would connect to the server and load the questions into the database.

Comment: Thanks very much for your detailed answer.

Answer (score 2):

1. Add [Android sqlite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) as a project dependency

```
    dependencies {
       compile 'com.readystatesoftware.sqliteasset:sqliteassethelper:+'
    }
```

2. Create a database (with all required tables) on your PC using any SQLite database manager like [SQLite Studio](https://sqlitestudio.pl/index.rvt)
3. Database created in step 2 would be a single file e.g (**Quiz.db**)
4. Now copy **Quiz.db** to your project **assets/databases/** folder
5. Create `DataBaseOpenHelper`

   ```
   public class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteAssetHelper {
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Quiz.db";
   private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

   public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context) {
       super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

   }
   ```

   }
6. Create `DataBaseAccess` class

   ```
   public class DatabaseAccess {

   private SQLiteOpenHelper openHelper;
   private SQLiteDatabase database;
   private static DatabaseAccess instance;

   /**
    * Private constructor to aboid object creation from outside classes.
    *
    * @param context
    */
   private DatabaseAccess(Context context) {
       this.openHelper = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
   }

   /**
    * Return a singleton instance of DatabaseAccess.
    *
    * @param context the Context
    * @return the instance of DabaseAccess
    */
   public static DatabaseAccess getInstance(Context context) {
       if (instance == null) {
           instance = new DatabaseAccess(context);
       }
       return instance;
   }

   /**
    * Open the database connection.
    */
   public void openDatabase() {

       this.database = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();


   }

   public SQLiteDatabase getWritableDatabase(){

       return openHelper.getWritableDatabase();

   }

   public SQLiteDatabase getReadabelDataBase()
   {
       return openHelper.getReadableDatabase();
   }



   /**
    * Close the database connection.
    */
   public void closeDatabase() {
       if (database != null) {
           this.database.close();
       }
   }
   ```

   }
7. Finally use it

   ```
   DatabaseAccess databaseAccess = DatabaseAccess.getInstance(context);
   databaseAccess.openDatabase();
   String query = "select * from  Questions order by QuestionID asc";
   Cursor cursor = databaseAccess.getWritableDatabase().rawQuery(query, null);
   // handle results here

   databaseAccess.closeDatabase();
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the reply!